# Wordpress Attachments (plugin) thumbnail help

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm implementing a design I've made on a Wordpress-installation. I've used the Attachments for some gallery function.

I can't however seem to find out how I can add a thumbnail. Can you help me?

```
<?php
  if( function_exists( 'attachments_get_attachments' ) )
  {
    $attachments = attachments_get_attachments();
    $total_attachments = count( $attachments );
    if( $total_attachments ) : ?>   

      <?php for( $i=0; $i<$total_attachments; $i++ ) : ?>
     <a href="<?php echo $attachments[$i]['location']; ?>" style="float:left;" rel="<?php echo $attachments[$i]['mime']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $attachments[$i]['location']; ?>" height="100" alt="<?php echo $attachments[$i]['title']; ?>" id="<?php echo $attachments[$i]['id']; ?>"><br><?php echo $attachments[$i]['caption']; ?></a>


      <?php endfor; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I tried with this, but it didn't help me:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(array(200,150)); ?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wordpress has its own namespace on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've used this:
http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/demo/timthumb-basic/

... it's really great!

Answer (score 0):

Use the native http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src to achieve this.

```
<?php
$post_id = $attachments[$i]['id'];
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_id, array(200,150) ); ?>

<img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" />
```

In your case it would become:

```
<?php
$post_id = $attachments[$i]['id'];
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_id, array(200,150) ); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $attachments[$i]['location']; ?>" style="float:left;" rel="<?php   echo $attachments[$i]['mime']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" alt<?php echo $attachments[$i]['title']; ?>" id="<?php echo $attachments[$i]['id']; ?>"><br><?php echo $attachments[$i]['caption']; ?></a>
```